# Adding block programmatically to InnerBlocks

Tags: block-editor

I am building a tab-style block, where you can choose tab in a header and enter the content in the section. For section, I am using InnerBlocks where you can insert specific "Tab" blocks separately created.
I set InnerBlocks property templateLock to 'all', so user cannot add tabs via usual interface. Instead, when "new tab" is clicked in header area, new Tab block should be programmatically inserted (via `dispatch('core/editor').insertBlock()`). This works only when Innerblocks template is not locked.
Any solutions? Unlock then lock Innerblocks? How?
Is there more elegant solution?

Comment: you don't need to use a template to achieve this, just say that the only child block allowed is the tab block, ad i the tab block say it can only be inserted in the tabs block. This is how columns work, "columns" and "column" blocks. You can also specify a custom appender component as part of inner blocks. Templates are not the solution

Comment: Ok. You pointed me to the right direction. I should just disable appender on the parent Innerblocks component.